# Missing ) after argument list jquery select by attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code yields an "missing ) after argument list" error.  However, I have checked out similar questions and have both escaped the quotes and made sure that the parenthesis are balanced.  I have been able to comment out these lines, and as no errors occur without them, I am certain that the problem occurs here.  What else can be causing this error with the code below?

```
for (var i=0; i< 4; i++){
    console.log($('div[aria-describedby=\'TakeJobDialog' + i + '\']']));
}
```

Comment: It should be `console.log($('div[aria-describedby="TakeJobDialog" ' + i + '\]'));`

Comment: You are having an extra `'` and an extra `]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a syntax error in your code. Use following:

```
for (var i=0; i< 4; i++){
    console.log($('div[aria-describedby=\'TakeJobDialog' + i + '\']'));
}
```